# Can not find PDOConnection.php

Tags: php, bash, laravel

I installed a Laravel project, as I am trying to learn the framework. I am now trying to work on a different machine and I can't set it up.

I get these errors:

```
blog git:(development) php artisan migrate:install

  [ErrorException]
  include(/home/ioto/www/my-bitbucket/blog/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

although when I try to check if the file actually exists I can see it but I can't access it:

```
➜  blog git:(development) cd vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver
➜  Driver git:(development) ls -lisa
total 112
 [...]
 26740122787838334 4 -rw-rw-rw- 0  777 ioto 3695 sep 10 15:00 PDOConnection.php
 [...]
➜  Driver git:(development) cat PDOConnection.php
cat: PDOConnection.php: No such file or directory
```

I am using "bash on ubuntu on windows"
I get the same errors if I try different things like other artisan commands, if I try to serve the application and so on. I tried a new composer update after deleting the vendor folder. Set chmod to 777, but I'm out of ideas...
Any suggestions on what can I try to debug this ?

Comment: Maybe you will find some inspiration here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory, although your problem seems specific to Laravel